# Unable to bring node inspector to debug express/nodejs app hosted on IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, express, mean.io, iisnode

I have hosted my express/nodejs app on IIS using IISNode.

This is how my `web.config` looks:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="NODE_ENV" value="production" />
</appSettings>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server/app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>


     <iisnode loggingEnabled="false" debuggingEnabled="true" debuggerPathSegment="debug" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Debug" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="server/app.js/debug*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="app" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server/app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />


  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I enter `http://localhost:6050/server/app.js/debug/` URL in chrome, I just see a panel like this:

[image]

Comment: I wonder what your console error is show in the screen cap. I am getting the same thing and working to debug it. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Not sure if it's worth it @SharpCoder, but if you wanted to share the error from your console, I may have a solution. I was able to get mine working.